# Sh leaks variables defined on function call (but not on command call)

Tags: bash, sh

Even though bash and sh are provided by the same package on my system, there are differences:

In bash:

```
$ echo $auie

$ auie=1 ls

$ echo $auie

$ testfn() { : ; }
$ auie=1 testfn
$ echo $auie
# Nothing
```

auie is defined only for the calls (ls, testfn), and is not leaked into the environment.

In sh:

```
$ echo $auie

$ auie=1 ls

$ echo $auie

$ testfn() { : ; }
$ auie=1 testfn
$ echo $auie
1
```

Here, auie is defined for the ls call only, BUT when the function call occurs, it "leaks" into the environment !

Why does sh behave as such ?

Comment: `sh` and `bash` are absolutely not the same thing. `bash` is the [Bourne Again Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), and `sh` is just a symlink to the default shell of your distro (in most cases, `dash`)

Comment: @Aserre Regardless, the difference is visible in `bash` if it is invoked as `sh`.

Comment: Because the function executes in the same process as the calling shell, an argument can be made that POSIX mandates the value "leak". `dash` behaves the same way. Here, `bash` takes the approach that the function, even if it is evaluated in the same shell, counts as a "separate" command and that pre-command modifiers should apply only to the shell. (`zsh` also treats the assignment as local to the function call, so there is clearly some confusion or disagreement about the "correct" behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [page of the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01), it appears that it is left undefined whether the value of `auie` should persist after the call to `testfn` returns:

> - If the command name is a function that is not a standard utility implemented as a function, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment during the execution of the function. It is unspecified:
>
>   - Whether or not the variable assignments persist after the completion of the function

It's not at all clear why `bash` would choose two different behaviors depending on how it is invoked. My guess is that `bash-as-sh` preserves backwards compatibility with some other shell (`ksh` [which does preserve the value] or the original Bourne shell), while `bash`-proper implements what the author considered "better" behavior.

In a non-exhaustive test, I can confirm that `dash` and `ksh` preserve the value, while `bash` and `zsh` do not.

```
% for sh in bash dash ksh zsh; do
for> echo $sh; $sh -c 'testfn () { : ; }; auie=1 testfn; echo $auie;'
for> done
bash

dash
1
ksh
1
zsh

192%
```